# Find the probability that there is at least one ball remaining in urn

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Infinitely many balls having labels 1,2,3,...Have an urn. Put balls 1 to 10 into the urn and choose one ball and throw it away. Next we place balls 11,12,..20 in the same urn and choose one ball, throw it away. Next we place balls 21 to 30 in the same urn and choose one ball, and throw this ball away. Similarly this goes on. Find the probability that there is at least one ball remaining in urn?

Attempt: Probability that ball 1 is not chosen $\frac{9}{10}$$\frac{18}{19}$$\frac{27}{28}$....

Probability that ball 2 is not chosen $\frac{9}{10}$$\frac{18}{19}$$\frac{27}{28}$....
....

Probability that ball 11 is not chosen $\frac{18}{19}$$\frac{27}{28}$.....
Since 11 cannot be chosen in 1st round
......

As you can see I am going nowhere. How to solve this?

Comment: I don't think the question makes sense. Which ball needs to remain in the urn? There's always going to be a ball in the urn.

Comment: Except the chosen one, all the remaining balls remain in urn.

Comment: Yes but when was the chosen one added? In the first $10$? In the first $100$? In any case, the probability that any individual ball remains in the urn after infinite iterations is $0$.

Comment: Lmao, what's the probability of a ball staying in an urn if it never gets put in?

Comment: Initially the ball is there sometime, As you can see from my attempt e.g  Probability that ball 1 is not chosen is not zero. hence ball 1 will not always be chosen. So maybe ball 1 is there in urn

Comment: Actually my point was that $\prod_{i=1}^\infty9i/(9i+1)=0$ so the probability that any of the first $10$ balls stay in the urn is also $0$. It makes sense if you think about it. If you have infinite chances of taking the ball out of the urn, clearly you're going to do it at some point.

Comment: Look at the products up to each term. First, we've got $9/10=0.9$, then $9\cdot18/(10\cdot19)\approx0.85$. Then $0.82, 0.80,\dots$. Clearly it's decreasing. With some analysis you can show that it goes to $0$.

Comment: Okay thanks. is it easy to show $\lim_{i\to \infty} $ product of $\frac{9i}{9i+1}$ tends to zero by some limit property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably ask yourself what it means to have a ball "remaining" in the urn after an infinite number of steps. This is a probabilistic version of the [Ross-Littlewood Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox).

As a longer answer: on one hand, the number of balls in the urn is clearly increasing and, at least, always positive. On the other, if you compute the probability any given ball is removed, you get 1. These are clearly incompatible conclusions.

### Extra

I have a messy way to justify that the probability of removal is actually 1.

You've shown that the chance any ball "remains" at the end is something like $\dfrac{9}{10}\cdot\dfrac{18}{19}\cdot\dfrac{27}{28}\cdot\dotsm= \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{9i}{9i+1}$. This product must converge (say, to $A_0$) by the monotone convergence theorem, as the partial products decrease and are bounded below by zero.

Consider the products $A_j$, for $j = 1, 2, \cdots, 8$ with $A_j = \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{9i+j}{9i+j + 1}$. By the same argument, each of these $A_j$ must converge. And, a key point, $0 \leq A_j \leq A_k$ for $j < k$.

Lastly, note that $A_0 A_1 \dotsm A_8 = \prod_{i=9}^{\infty} \dfrac{i}{i+1} = 0$, by a telescoping argument. And we know that if the product of numbers is zero, at least one of the numbers is zero. Therefore, $A_0$ must be 0.

I'm stuck wondering how to show $A_4$ is $0$ right now.

Comment: How did you get the probability that any given ball is removed is 1

Comment: See edit for an argument that the probability of removal is 1.